# Как убрать запятую между строками таблицы

Tags: javascript

Вывожу в таблицу данные. Между строками таблицы выводиться запятая. Как ее убрать?
const arrByLang = externalService.getCountryListByLanguage('English');

```
tbody.innerHTML = arrByLang.map((country) => 
    ` <tr>
      <td>${country.name}</td>
    <td>${country.capital}</td>
    <td>${country.region}</td>
    <td>${getLanguages(country.languages)}</td>
    <td>${country.area}</td>
    <td><img src="${country.flagURL}"></td>
        </tr> `
 )
```

Comment: а, с мапой теперь более понятно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`map` возвращает массив. `innerHTML` принимает на вход строку. Соответственно, массив неявно преобразуется в строку. По умолчанию разделитель для соединения элементов массива - запятая. Для решения проблемы, сделайте `join` данных с разделителем в виде пустого символа. Например

```
tbody.innerHTML = arrByLang.map((country) => .... ).join('');
```

```js
document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = [1,2,3];
document.getElementById('test2').innerHTML = [1,2,3].join('');
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
<div id="test2"></div>
```